# mmenu sliding effect lagging in iOS 7

Tags: animation, mmenu

the mmenu sliding has an lagging effect... is it possible to do with CSS3 transitions ? the jquery mobile doesnt have this problem... but I need this plugin mmenu help me...

The problem is only on mobile devices ... on computer it works smooth...

```
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('nav#menu').mmenu({
        classes: 'mm-light',
        },{
                    transitionDuration : 0,
             });
});
```

I tried to disable with "transitionDuration" but no luck...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051887/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-slide-animation-in-mmenu