# Is it possible to remove the slide animation in mmenu?

Tags: jquery, animation, mmenu

I can't find the setting to remove the opening slide animation introduced by mmenu. I have
managed to get it to close instantly by setting transition duration to zero.

```
$("nav#menu").mmenu({
  searchfield: false,
  slidingSubmenus: false,
  header: {
    add : true,
    update : true,
    title : 'application'
  },
}, {
  transitionDuration: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the values from 0.4s to 0.0s like below in
the jquery.mmenu.all.css file i managed to open the menu without the slide animation.

```
.mm-fixed-bottom {
  -webkit-transition: none 0.0s ease;
  -moz-transition: none 0.0s ease;
  -ms-transition: none 0.0s ease;
  -o-transition: none 0.0s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you need 'transitionDuration' option, set it to 0.
look on this [page](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/options/configuration.html).

Comment: Yes as stated in the question i have set that to zero already, but that only works for closing, not opening.

Comment: Better to post your code. But if I understood correctly this plugin use animation duration from css. Check css for transition properties. In file jquery.mmenu.all.css I found several properties.

Comment: Thanks for your useful advice. I managed to find out in the css file which values to change in order to remove the animation.